# Column values have /223 added after separate() function was used. How to fix that?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have following code that separates column *Year* into columns start year and end year of series (that are separated by â€ in the csv file).

```
series %>%
   separate(Year, into =c("year_start", "year_end"), sep = "â€", convert= TRUE) %>% 
   mutate(year_end = coalesce(year_end, year_start))
```

But after that action *\223* is added at the beginning of each row in *year_end* (can be seen on added screenshot). How to fix that?
Console output:

```
> series %>%
+   separate(Year, into =c("year_start", "year_end"), sep = "â€", convert= TRUE) %>% 
+   mutate(year_end = coalesce(year_end, year_start))
Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 29 rows [3, 4, 36, 46, 57, 83, 88, 107, 110, 119, 122, 127, 136, 159, 164, 166, 171, 191, 192, 193, ...].
```

[image]

Comment: Try: `'sep=\\â€'`

Comment: @TarJae Tried it, but it has the same outcome